# How can I change the file ownership to root on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ownership

How can I change the file ownership to root on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5):

Use the command:

```
sudo chown root file.name
```

[`chown`](http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/chown.html) is tool for changing ownership. As root account is superuser type to change ownership to root you need to run `chown` command as superuser with `sudo`.

Comment: Its hard to do it without sodo. Hope added description is enough.

Comment: What is “sodo”? :-) I fixed that for you. However, there is one more question: What about changing group? With your command, the file would be still writable for the original owner. I know that OP did not specify what their requirement regarding groups is but you should at least mention it in the answer.

Comment: why isn't it `root:root`?